# Android Studio debug tooltip keyboard shortcut

Tags: android-studio

is there any way to display tooltip with variable value while debugging? I mean keyboard shortcut no mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean how can you show the value of the variable using keyboard shortcuts?

Assuming that you can highlight the variable of interest using the keyboard, you can press Alt+F8 (Option+F8 for Mac), which will bring up an Evaluate dialog box for the highlighted variable.  Press Enter and it should show the value.

You can also add the variable to the "Watch" box in the Debugger and it will automatically show the value of the variable as you step past it.

Finally, when debugging, the values of each variable are shown in shadow text to the right of the variable inside the code itself.